# How to get inline/block items using Jquery/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My issue is simple but I am not that pro at JS. I have a list of items in a `<table>` where every product shows their price. But I want to change these prices to **on sale prices**. My strategy was to load both prices in a tuple:

```
 <td>
 <span class="precio-normal">@item.Precio</span>
 <span class="precio-mayorista" style="display: none;">@item.PrecioOferta</span> 
 </td>
```

I have coded a toggle button to activate/deactivate **on sale prices**

```
    <script>
   
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('customSwitch1')

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            $(".precio-mayorista").css("display", "block");
            $(".precio-normal").css("display", "none");
        } else {
            $(".precio-mayorista").css("display", "none");
            $(".precio-normal").css("display", "block");
        }
    })

</script>
```

This is my code to get specific data in the table using child and parent nodes.

```
var parent = $(this).parent().parent()
var child = parent.children('td');
var i = 0;

var data = new Array();

child.each(function () {

    switch (i) {

        case 5:
            data[5] = $(this).text();
            break;
    }

    i++;

});
```

My code works OK but my problem is that `data[5]` is getting both values even the `none` one. I only want to capture visible items. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not mix DOM and jQuery. SO much easier to debug if you are consistent

```js
$('#customSwitch1').on('change', function() {
  $(".precio-mayorista").toggle(this.checked)
  $(".precio-normal").toggle(!this.checked);
})
```

and

```
const data = $(".somElementClass")
  .filter(function() { return $(this).is(":visible") })
  .map(function() { $(this).text() }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `:visible` selector so you only get the text of the visible spans.

```
        case 5:
            data[5] = $(this).find("span:visible").text();
            break;
```